# Remapping serial ports in 14.04 using udev rules not working?

Tags: 14.04, udev, serial-port

So I have a udev rules file to remap the serial ports as they are not in the order required. The rules work fine on SLES11 SP1 but do not seem to do anything on 14.04.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="platform", DRIVERS=="serial8250", KERNELS=="serial8250", KERNEL=="ttyS2", NAME="ttyS10"
SUBSYSTEM=="platform", DRIVERS=="serial8250", KERNELS=="serial8250", KERNEL=="ttyS3", NAME="ttyS11"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{id}=="PNP0501", KERNEL=="ttyS4", NAME="ttyS12"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{id}=="PNP0501", KERNEL=="ttyS5", NAME="ttyS13"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS6", NAME="ttyS2"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS7", NAME="ttyS3"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS8", NAME="ttyS4"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS9", NAME="ttyS5"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS10", NAME="ttyS6"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS11", NAME="ttyS7"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS12", NAME="ttyS8"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="serial", ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1415", KERNEL=="ttyS13", NAME="ttyS9"
```

I have tried using setserial a swell but with no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`udev`has been changed, it supports `NAME` only for network interfaces nothing more.

- From [the release note](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP1/), SLES11 SP1 is Version 11.1.1.10 (2012-04-17), so it should be same as Ubuntu 12.04.

  ```
     NAME
         Match the name of the node or network interface. It can be used
         once the NAME key has been set in one of the preceding rules.
     ...

     NAME
         What a network interface should be named.

         Also, as a temporary workaround, this is what a device node should
         be named; usually the kernel provides the defined node name or
         creates and removes the node before udev even receives any event.
         Changing the node name from the kernel's default creates
         inconsistencies and is not supported. If the kernel and NAME
         specify different names, an error is logged. udev is only expected
         to handle device node permissions and to create additional
         symlinks, not to change kernel-provided device node names. Instead
         of renaming a device node, SYMLINK should be used. However, symlink
         names must never conflict with device node names, as that would
         result in unpredictable behavior.
  ```
- Where in Ubuntu 14.04

  ```
     NAME
         Match the name of a network interface. It can be used once the NAME
         key has been set in one of the preceding rules.
     ...
     NAME
         The name to use for a network interface. The name of a device node
         cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.
  ```

Note, the 1st NAME is for condition match and 2nd NAME is for action. You can compare both man pages at [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/udev.7.html)

For complete answer, you should look for creating new symlinks instead using `SYMLINK` udev action.