# How can I instruct ubuntu to map drives to specific /dev/xxx

Tags: hard-drive, udev, storage

This is a reverse question to tons of questions about how to identify which physical drive matches `/dev/sdx`. I want to avoid having to ask that question when a drive fails.

I have bought an adapter capable of serving 8 drives (9211-8i). Both SFF-8087 cables are nicely marked so that I know which physical drive is which.

However, the attached drives are mapped as `/dev/sdx`

Just for reference, my M.2 boot drive nicely mounts as `/dev/nvmxxx` which nicely distinguishes it from the other drives in the system.

So, how can I instruct ubuntu device mapper to map my controller attached drives as something distinct & EXACTLY matching the physical port a drive is attached to, e.g. `/dev/scsi[abcdefgh]`? In fact, I'd even prefer numeric port numbers, but I'm not sure it matches unix mapping rules where drives are marked with letters, then followed by partition numbers, e.g. `/dev/sda` -> `/dev/sda1`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `/dev/disk/by-path/`, which essentially does this. The other way is to reference it by UUID or Label, which is a property of the partition, and not the hardware. If you reference disks by UUID, this will not change, even if you move the drive to a different computer.

```
$ ls /dev/disk/
by-id  by-label  by-path  by-uuid

$ ls /dev/disk/by-path/
pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0        pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2
pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1  pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5
```

As you can see, this uniquely identifies the drive depending on path, including bus connection. These files are a symlink to the actual device:

```
$ ls -la pci-0000\:03\:00.0-scsi-0\:0\:0\:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 18 09:08 pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
```

To identify a drive, the utility `lsblk` is useful:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda      8:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  7.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0  383M  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  247M  0 rom
```

To see the UUID of a disk, you can run `sudo lsblk -f`. This will show the UUID, which you will find in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` as well:

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
[...]
    └─system-swap  swap          73195006-1ae6-4d5f-87df-78cb52f48f15   [SWAP]
$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/73195006-1ae6-4d5f-87df-78cb52f48f15
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 20 17:33 /dev/disk/by-uuid/73195006-1ae6-4d5f-87df-78cb52f48f15 -> ../../dm-3
```

This can also be used in fstab. For instance:

```
UUID=f0a2eebe-1791-4c44-ab86-75ea81a82c43 /boot ext4 acl,user_xattr 1 2
```

will mount the partition with that UUID on /boot.

Comment: You might want to include `blkid` or similar to identify UUID and `ls -l ls /dev/disk/by-label/` for lable

Comment: OK, this is identifying, but how do I instruct udev to actually map them to something based on UUID?

Comment: @velis They **are** mapped by UUID in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.

Comment: Put an entry, by lable or uuid, in /etc/fstab https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab or if you must use udev see https://superuser.com/questions/521402/use-uuid-in-udev-rules-and-mount-usb-drive-on-media-uuid

Comment: I don't think I specified my question adequately: I'm not asking about how to mount an existing drive and how to find it so I could mount it. I'm saying I don't want it to be **MAPPED** as /dev/sde --> instead I'd like to map it as /dev/ **myidentifier** x

Comment: Why not use the `/dev/disk/by-*/` then? The label you can set freely, so this can be used as your identifier.  If you want you can also make udev add links in /dev/ for the devices.

Comment: So there's a command which I can use to set a disk's label and then use a /dev/disk/by-label/something to access it? That would definitely work for me.

Comment: Yes, there is. This differs from FS to FS, but with EXT2/3/4 Filesystems, you can use `sudo e2label /dev/foo "mylabel"`. Or you could go by path or UUID.

Comment: @velis. No way to change the dev name from udev, but you may use its `SYMLINK` as you want. Check this post https://askubuntu.com/q/810451/26246

Comment: I do not know how initially I did not see that /dev/disk/by-path IDENTIFIES the disk for me. I can't map this, for sure, but it's enough when I see a disk drop out of an array to know exactly which one it is that dropped out. Answer accepted.